# como Cargar datos con Vue axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Estoy empezando a desarrollar un proyecto con nodeJs, express y sequelize (postgresSQL), quiero agregarle las funciones que ofrece Vue Axios a este proyecto pero no logro entender como trabaja esta librería. Si alguien aquí que pueda ayudarme con algún ejemplo o material se los agradecería

Comment: Podrias ver [ask]?.. Vue es una cosa, Axios es otra cosa distinta. Es mas, las dos viven por separado y hacen cosas distintas.. Deberias poner tus idea en orden.. viste ya https://vuejs.org/?

Comment: ok disculpe es que estoy nuevo en esto, lo que quiero hacer son peticiones e inserciones a la base datos sin tener que estar recargando la pagina, he visto algunos ejemplos donde hacen uso de APIs pero no entiendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios es una herramienta que permite consumir y mostar datos desde una API y puede ser utilizada en framework como Vue, Si lo que quieres es efectivamente consumir una API con Axios, lo primero que tienes que hacer es instalar Axios en tu proyecto de Vue por medio de npm o yard.  Luego puedes comenzar a utilizarla.  Acá te muestro un ejemplo de un get que te permitá obtener los datos.

created() {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      this.info = response
    })

Recuerda que la url es tu ruta para llegar a la API que se conecta directamente con tu base de datos.

Comment: no es que axios permita consultar datos desde una API es que axios permite hacer peticiones de tipo AJAX, por otro lado para usarlo no es necesario usar yarn o npm, se puede invocar solo en la etiqueta script